# Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting this crash on crashlytics only for iOS 12.

Does anyone know what this is?
Looks to be something related to push notifications but we don't have that in the app yet.

`Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens when you rename files outside of Xcode, you should remove the files from the project and reimport them, hope it helps :)

Comment: But it doesn't happen while debugging. only the released version, shouldn't I see this in debug mode too?

Comment: @AleksanderAleksic agree with you.